# Randomize Next Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an application that has a question on each page.  Currently I have a button where OnClick points to the function below, but I would like it to choose a random page.  I have 10 .aspx pages.  How can I do this?

```
protected void newWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Question2.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
protected void newWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int next = new Random().Next( 10 ) + 1; // 1..10
    Response.Redirect(string.Format( "Question{0}.aspx", next ));
}
```

Comment: Works great!  Is there any 'simple' way that this can avoid going back to a page that has been visited?

Comment: Use sessions / cookies to keep track of which pages have been visited already.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int GetRandomNumberBewteen1And10()
{
    var r = new Random();
    return r.Next(1, 11);
}
```

Comment: r.Next(min, max) excludes max - r.Next(1, 10) will only return 1..9

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your list of possible pages into an array and then use the Random() method to pull out a random index from that array.

```
List<string> pages = new List<string>({
    "Question2.aspx",
    "Question3.aspx",
    // etc.
});
Random r = new Random();
int randomIdx =r.Next(0, pages.Count-1);


Response.Redirect(pages[randomIdx];
```